# How to do a recursive procedure to represent a triangle in the upper half of the matrix in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I did an Algorithm to print a triangle in the upper half of the matrix (**without recursive function**) but now i want to do it recursively can anyone Help?
Thanks

[**CLICK HERE TO  SEE AN EXAMPLE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yov55.png)

My python code:

```
def T(row,column):  
  print("Row: ",row)
  print("Column", column)
  if row != column and row%2 == 0:
    print("Please enter valid number")
  else:    
    matrix = []
    start = 1
    cteRow = row
    cteColumn = column    
    for i in range(0,column):  
      matrix.append(list(range(start,row + 1)))
      start = start + cteRow
      row = row + cteColumn        
    print("The Matrix: \n")
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
      for j in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[i][j], end= " ")
      print()
    print()
    length = len(matrix)
    middle = int(length/2)    
    for i in range(length):         
      for j in range(length):              
        matrix[i][j] = 0
        if (middle + i)<= length and (middle - i)>= 0:
         matrix[i][middle] = 1
         myRangeList=list(range(middle-i,middle+i+1))    
         for n in myRangeList:           
            matrix[i][n] = 1                      
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ")       
      print() 
T(5,5)
```

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: Ok thank you i appreciate your advice and sorry for my bad question ^-^

Answer (score 1):

To make it recursive, you have to come up with a method to convert the result of a smaller matrix into a larger one.

for example:

```
From T(3,5) --> T(4,7)

0 0 1 0 0       0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0       0 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1       0 1 1 1 1 1 0
                1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The transformation could be adding zeros on each side and a line of 1s at the bottom:

```
0 0 1 0 0       0 x x x x x 0      0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0       0 x x x x x 0      0 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1       0 x x x x x 0      0 1 1 1 1 1 0
                1 1 1 1 1 1 1      1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This will be easy if the parameters provided fit the triangle size exactly: rows = (columns+1)/2.  You can handle the disproportionate dimensions by padding the result from an appropriate size ratio with zeros so that the function only needs to handle proper proportions:

```
def R(rows,cols):
    if not cols%2:  # must have odd number of columns (pad trailing zero)
        return [ row+[0] for row in R(rows,cols-1)]
    height = (cols+1)//2
    if rows>height: # too high, pad with lines of zeros
        return R(height,cols)+[[0]*cols for _ in range(rows-height)]
    if rows<height:                           # not high enough
        return R(height,cols)[:rows]          #    truncate bottom
    if cols == 1:                             # base case (1,1)
        return [[1]]
    result = R(rows-1,cols-2)                 # Smaller solution
    result = [[0]+row+[0] for row in result]  # pad with zeros
    result += [[1]*cols]                      # add line of 1s
    return result
```

*The function only generates the matrix. User input and printing should always be separate from data manipulation (especially for recursion)*

output:

```
for row in R(5,5): print(*row) 

0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

*Note that this will work for any combination of row & column sizes but, if you always provide the function with a square matrix, only the "upper half" will contain the triangle because triangle height = (columns+1)/2.  It would also be unnecessary to ask the user for both a number of rows and a number of columns if the two are required to be equal.*

For only square matrices with an odd number of columns, the process can be separated in a recursive part and a padding function that uses it:

```
def R(cols):
    if cols == 1: return [[1]]                # base case (1,1)        
    result = R(cols-2)                        # Smaller solution
    result = [[0]+row+[0] for row in result]  # pad with zeros
    result += [[1]*cols]                      # add line of 1s
    return result

def T(n):
    return R(n)+[[0]*n]*((n-1)//2)  # square matrix with padding

for row in T(7): print(*row)

0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```